# SSIS Package System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: ssis, out-of-memory, script-component

When I was runnig SSIS package, some  Data Flow Tasks throw exception `System.OutOfMemoryException`. I use Script Components in Data Flow Tasks.This script components execute queries, gets data from source database, this datas about 1,5GB , I keep this data in DataSet. Data Flow Task fail in script components PreExecute method. Here is my code block;

```
 public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();


    connStr = this.Variables.DestinationConnectionString.ToString();
    //cmParams = this.Connections.DestinationConnection;
    conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr.ToString());
    conn.Open();

    tableAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ID,OLD_ID FROM ADDRESS WHERE OLD_ID IS NOT NULL AND TENANTID=" + this.Variables.TenantID.ToString(), conn);
    tableDataSet = new DataSet();
    tableDataSet1 = new DataSet();
    tableDataSet2 = new DataSet();
    tableAdapter.Fill(tableDataSet, "Table");
    tableAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ID,OLD_ID FROM COMPANY WHERE OLD_ID IS NOT NULL AND TENANTID=" + this.Variables.TenantID.ToString(), conn);
    tableAdapter1.Fill(tableDataSet1, "Table1");
    tableAdapter2 = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ID,OLD_ID FROM ENTITY WHERE OLD_ID IS NOT NULL AND TENANTID=" + this.Variables.TenantID.ToString(), conn);
    tableAdapter2.Fill(tableDataSet2, "Table2");

}
```

[Error Screen Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbf0J.png)

[Task Manager Screen Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYTOq.png)

My package size is 4069KB.
Data Flow Task max buffer size: 20MB
Data Flow Task max buffer max rows : 10000

Can any one help me about this exception?

Comment: Do you have that much RAM free? And harddrive in your C drive for SSIS temporaries.

Comment: Yes, I have.  Memory usage approximately 60% in error occure. And I have 8GB RAM. I set BLOBTempStoragePath and BufferTempStoragePath  in C drive. 32GB free space avaible in C drive. But i think , that error irrelevant this TempPath. Because this selected data keeping in RAM.